# Efficiency in array element replacement

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, list-manipulation

Suppose I have two lists:

```
list1={{-4,10,3},{8,-2,7},{10,-8,-3}, {9,9,-10}, {9,-3,-2}, {-5,-3,5}}
list2={{-4,10,0},{8,-2,-3},{10,-8,-4}, {9,9,10}, {9,-3,1}, {-5,-3,8}}
```

The goal is to identify elements in each sublist of `list1` whose third element is larger than a given criterion, and replace the third element in the corresponding tuple in `list2` with $0$.

Let's say the threshold is $1$, then the result would be:

```
result = {{-4, 10, 0}, {8, -2, 0}, {10, -8, -4}, {9, 9, 10}, {9, -3, 1}, {-5, -3, 0}}
```

I already have code to solve this, but I am looking for a more efficient way to do this without `Do`.

I can achieve the result by using:

```
out = Reap[Do[If[list1[[n, 3]] > 1, Sow[n], Continue], {n, 1, Dimensions[list1[[1]]}]][[2, 1]];
Do[list2[[out[[s]], 3]] = 0.0, {s, 1, Dimensions[out][[1]]}]
```

This is good for a small list, however I need an efficient way to do this with approximately 265,000 tuples. It would be a plus to keep something similar to the first step, where the points are identified and stored. The second step can be done on multiple lists, without doing the identifying of the points each time. 
Any ideas how to improve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t = 1;
list2[[All, -1]] = list2[[All, -1]] UnitStep[t - list1[[All, -1]]];
list2 == result
```

> True

Timing comparison with OP's and MarcoB's methods:

```
SeedRandom[1]
l1 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3000000, 3}];
l2 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3000000, 3}];
l2a = l2;
l2b = l2;
l2c = l2;

t = 1;
l2a[[All, -1]] = l2a[[All, -1]] UnitStep[t - l1[[All, -1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.213539

```
(out = Reap[Do[If[l1[[n, 3]] > 1, Sow[n], Continue], {n, 1, 
        Dimensions[l1][[1]]}]][[2, 1]];
   Do[l2b[[out[[s]], 3]] = 0.0, {s, 1, Dimensions[out][[1]]}]) // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 7.655828

```
With[{positions = Join[#, {-1}] & /@ Position[l1, {__, _?(# > t &)}]},
     l2c = ReplacePart[l2c, positions -> 0]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 6.617897

```
l2a == l2b == l2c
```

> True

Comment: Im not sure this solves my problem, note you have altered some values in list 2 that didnt need to be altered. All third elements in the tuples should be the same in `list2`, except the ones matching the criteria in `list1`.

Comment: @Giovanni, fixed now.

Comment: Brilliant, the UnitStep is really smart! Thanks!

Comment: @GiovanniBaez, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

[@kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176313/27951) is very elegant. Here is an alternative that explicitly stores the positions of such tuples, and for the sake of variety:

```
threshold = 1;

With[
  {positions = Join[#, {-1}] & /@ Position[list1, {__, _?(# > threshold &)}]},
  ReplacePart[list2, positions -> 0]
]

% == result

(* Out: 
 {{-4, 10, 0}, {8, -2, 0}, {10, -8, -4}, {9, 9, 10}, {9, -3, 1}, {-5, -3, 0}}
 True
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ReplacePart`, after first identifying the positions with `Position`, and filtering out to the ones that are position 3 with `Cases`:

```
ReplacePart[list2, Cases[Position[list1, x_ /; x > 1 ], {_, 3}] -> 0]
```