# Loss of 1 to 1 mapping due to duplicate in Association

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

The main goal of this procedure is to first rotate an array of 3D coordinate leaving z untouched,finding the positions of tuples with z larger than some value, and then mapping those positions to the un-rotated array.

I will provide an example to clear things up. Let the un-rotated array be `test1` and the rotated one `test2`. Element #2 of `test1` is `{0.00195313, 0.00112764, 6.76149*10^-14}` this gets rotated to `{-0.00195313, -0.00112764, 6.76149*10^-14}` in `test2` at the same position,e.i. `test2[[2]]`. This rotated element may not be part of the original array, I used `Nearest` to find the closest element to this an then its corresponding position. The closest element in the original array is the one with coordinates X and Y `{-0.00195313, -0.00112737}` and its in position `131412`. I am using the approach described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176311/efficiency-in-array-element-replacement/176313?noredirect=1#comment462740_176313) to select the elements I'd like to keep as it is the fastest method I've found. So after all this the element in position #2 of this filtered array should go to position `131412`.

The problem seems to arise when using the nearest function, it might be mapping multiple elements in one array to one in the other one. I dont know how to get around this issue.

Here is my attempt at this:

```
test1 = Import["C:"path"jr12.csv", "CSV"];
test2 = Import["C:"path"Rjr12.csv", "CSV"];
test22d = test2[[All, {1, 2}]];
test12d = test1[[All, {1, 2}]];
index1 = PositionIndex[test12d];
n = Nearest[test12d];
pos = Join @@ index1 /@ (Join @@ (n /@ test22d));
ind = PositionIndex[pos];
outrot = UnitStep[0.1 - test2[[All, -1]]];
out = ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[outrot][[1]]];

result = Reap[Do[Sow[{out[[n]]*outrot[[ind[n]]]}], {n, 1,Dimensions[outrot][[1]]}]][[2, 1]];
(*Failure point*)
(*Part::pkspec1: The expression Missing[KeyAbsent,131157] cannot be used    as a part specification.
 Part::pkspec1: The expression Missing[KeyAbsent,218453] cannot be used as a part specification 
 General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.*)


Dimensions[test2]
(*{261972, 3}*)
Dimensions[pos]
(*{261972}*)
Dimensions[ind]
(*{261801}  Loss of elements*)
```

Any advise or fix on this attempt would be appreciated.

Data is available here:
  [test1](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ABNqdgGdmYek8TwGby3sPGKjcB2IrYuo) 
  [test2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pg4Dn5uEt_LaqA1xPf96-LdjNRHrhOef)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `nearOriginal = Nearest[MapIndexed[Most@#1 -> First@#2 &]@test1]; test2[[Ordering@Ordering@nearOriginal[test2[[All, ;; 2]], 1]]]`.

Comment: Why does `result` contain only zeros and ones?

Comment: @Coolwater The point of that list is to later multiply it by the z component of the original list, the reference explains the procedure, either keeping them intact or setting them to zero.

Comment: @Edmund the result Im looking for is just an array of 1s and 0s which are filtered in the rotated array but then mapped to the unrotated positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a little more time I came up with something that solves the issue, but it is not that elegant, in my opinion.

```
test1 = Import["C:"Path"\\jr12.csv", "CSV"];
test2 = Import["C:\\Pat\\Rjr12.csv", "CSV"];
test22d = test2[[All, {1, 2}]];
test12d = test1[[All, {1, 2}]];
index1 = PositionIndex[test12d];
n = Nearest[test12d];
pos = Join @@ index1 /@ (Join @@ (n /@ test22d));
outrot = UnitStep[0.1 - test2[[All, -1]]];
out = ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[outrot][[1]]];
map = Reap[Do[Sow[{m, pos[[m]]}], {m, 1, Dimensions[pos][[1]]}]][[2,1]];
result = Reap[Do[Sow[out[[n]]*outrot[[map[[n, 2]]]]], {n, 1,Dimensions[outrot][[1]]}]][[2, 1]]
```

Or alternatively:

```
pos = Nearest[test1[[All, {1, 2}]] -> "Index", test2[[All, {1, 2}]], 1][[All, 1]];
result = UnitStep[0.1 - test2[[All, -1]]][[pos]];
```

I got rid of the problematic part by not using the `PositionIndex` and just creating a 2d array of coordinates which houses the position of the rotated array in the first index and the position to which it should be mapped on the second index,`map`. This DOESN'T solve the duplicate problem, just bypasses it. If anyone has more elegant solution feel free to share.

Comment: Is `result` from that code incorrect? If not how is the problem not solved?

Comment: The `result` is correct, I just really wanted to solve the duplicate issue explicitly.